# Convert Date time to carbon Instance

Tags: php, html, laravel, php-carbon

I'm using date time input field

```
<input type="datetime-local">
```

It returns a formatted date time `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm`

Now i want to convert this format to `Y-m-d H:i` using `php-carbon` Package.

I have tried

```
 \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat(

    'yyyy-MM-ddTh:mm', $this->start_date

 )->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But it failed.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the import format like: `'Y-m-dTH:i', $this->start_date)` ?

Comment: Yes i did but it also failed Saying ```The separation symbol could not be found Unexpected data found.```

Comment: I think syntax error proper syntax Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);

Comment: Can you add a raw date from the `$this->start_date` var to the question?

Comment: ```$this->start_date``` it came from ```FormRequest``` class in laravel. This solution worked well  ```\Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->start_date)->format('Y-m-d H:i');``` Thanks for helping :) @Claudio

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use `Carbon::parse` for date parse.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->start_date)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```